# Checking URL variable for Multiple Query Strings

Tags: php

Currently I have:
`$_GET["number"] == "one"`

I'm trying to have php check the url for `?number=one`, `?number=two`, or `?number=three`.

How do I simplify the code below so it checks for all 3:

```
(isset($_GET["number"] == "one" && $_GET["number"] == "two" && $_GET["number"] == "three")
```

Comment: Use `||` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['number'])) {
  $options = array("one", "two", "three");
  in_array($_GET['number'], $options);
}
```

This way you can extend your options later. The first line is to make sure that when the number parameter is not present, do not execute the code part, you might not need it. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php for the core part.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below:

```
$arg = array('one', 'two', 'three');
if (isset($_GET["number"]) && in_array($_GET["number"], $arg, TRUE)) {
    // do the stuff
    switch ($_GET["number"]) {
        case 'one':
            // code to be executed for one
            break;
        case 'two':
            // code to be executed for two
            break;
        case 'three':
            // code to be executed for three
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you cannot put condition inside your `isset()` statement.Then if you want to check for either of item existence then use OR (`||`) operator. If you want to check existence of all items use AND (`&&`) operator. So in you code do like this

```
if(isset($_GET['number']) && ($_GET['number'] == 'one' || $_GET['number'] == 'two' || $_GET['number'] == 'three'))
{
   // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are searching for something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET["number"]) && ($_GET["number"] == "one" || $_GET["number"] == "two" || $_GET["number"] == "three")){
// Do something here
}
```